# Global server session in express node.js app

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express

How should I gave access to the current session to the modules of my node.js app considering that I can only get it inside the request's function?
It's a fairly complex but modular app and passing the session around seems a bit difficult, and I would have to reimplement a lot of things.
Ideally i would attach it to an object exported with module.exports and require it in other modules. But I'm afraid that on concurrent requests it would get overwritten and I could end up with conflicts.

Comment: How would it get overwritten on concurrent requests? Do you have an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using [express-domain-middleware](https://www.npmjs.org/package/express-domain-middleware) which binds incoming request & response from express to a new [domain](http://nodejs.org/api/domain.html).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried **[res.locals](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.locals)** ?
In the Official Docs, it says "Response local variables are scoped to the request, thus only available to the view(s) rendered during that request / response cycle, if any. This object is useful for exposing request-level information such as the request pathname, authenticated user, user settings etcetera. "

When your middleware/route callback is called, you can define `res.locals.myProp = "some value"` and access it from a view, using `locals.myProp`.

Comment: I don't need the data in a view but in other node modules that are required based on the current route.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I read your post too fast.
You could define `app.locals.myProp` on each request... but you may end up with the same issue you are afraid of. I don't know, I've honestly never tried that. Maybe someone will come with a better solution